# Argon2 Verify Always Returns True

Tags: node.js

I'm using argon2 with nodejs and I'm trying to verify a password:

```
global.user = [{username:"u1", password:"hidden"}];
  // run the password in the argon2 hashing alg
  const signup = async function(password) {
    // hash password using argon2i (mainly for passwords)
    var key = await argon2.hash(password, {
      type: argon2.argon2i,
      timeCost: 200,
      hashLength: 128,
    });
    return key;
  }

  var k = signup(req.body.password);
  k.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    global.user.push({username:req.body.username, password:result})
    res.json(global.user);
  })

  var success = false;
  if(argon2.verify(item.password, "meow")) {
    console.log(req.body.password);
    console.log(item.password);
    success = true;
  }
```

argon2.verify() always returns true no matter what I compare the hash to but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `argon2.verify` returns a promise, which when implicitly converted to a boolean is true. Use `await argon2.verify` instead.